# Marker mislocated with certain option disabled

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to place a marker with the Maps JS API, while using the `optimized: false` option. This results in the marker getting placed in Kasakhstan, instead of Norway. If I zoom to zoom level 0 (world zoom), the marker relocates to its intended location. Any clues?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLgn6jqm/)

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5.4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(72.84664426123108, -32.280699735104044) // norway
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(64.426895, 11.496360),
    map: map,
    optimized: false
});
```

Comment: if I test it the marker gets placed in Norway, maybe you should change your center position of the map to: (64.5753756,17.8820071)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zoom must be an integer.   `zoom: 5.4` doesn't work.

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uLgn6jqm/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;
var marker = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(72.84664426123108, -32.280699735104044) // norway
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(64.426895, 11.496360),
    map: map,
    optimized: false
  });
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```

```css
body,
html,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```